# Do fundamental matrix and essential matrix change with different photos?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I calibrated 2 cameras as stereo system and found fundamental and essential matrix. To do it I used chessboard pattern. 
It's interesting to know if they are the same for these 2 cameras if I will take different photos (not chessboard)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about the properties of a photography system, rather than the programming to obtain these properties. [photography.SE] might be a better fit.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question seems to not fit the rules of Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read the [list of topics one can ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). If you have a question about how to programmatically obtain these matrices, or how to use them in a programming context, that'd be perfectly fine here. This, however, is not programming related alas.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The fundamental and the essential matrix are properties of the camera system, not of the images, so they remain the same.

Even better, if you can reliably replicate the camera system (e.g. you buy a stereo camera), they should be the same across different camera systems (up to manufacturing errors).